# jQuery multiple ajax loading animations on calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On a page I have different element which I bound yo different Ajax calls.
For example one a.click is requesting x.php another one down the same page requests y.php.

What I like to do is place an individual loading image for each.
ajaxStart and ajaxStop won't do it since they are fired everytime, no matter which one called.

So how I can do it for individual calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks in the individual `$.ajax` calls like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myPage1.html',
  beforeSend: function() { 
    $("#loading1").fadeIn();
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //Current code
  },
  complete: function() {
    $("#loading1").fadeOut('fast');
  }
});


$.ajax({
  url: 'myPage2.html',
  beforeSend: function() { 
    $("#loading2").fadeIn();
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //Current code
  },
  complete: function() {
    $("#loading2").fadeOut('fast');
  }
});
```

[See here for a full list of available callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options)